# Why we need braces in renderItem() method for FlatList in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm not sure why we need braces outside of `item` for renderItem in the following code snippet whereas for keyExtractor there's no braces. I guess this has something to do with object destructuring, but what does `item` here referring to? There's no field with the name 'item' in the `friends` object, how could it be object destructuring?

```js
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList}  from "react-native";

const ListScreen = () => {
    const friends = [
        {name: "friend #1"},
        {name: "friend #2"},
        {name: "friend #3"},
        {name: "friend #4"},
        {name: "friend #5"},
    ];

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>This is the ListScreen Component</Text>
            <FlatList
                keyExtractor={(friend) => friend.name}
                data={friends}
                renderItem={({item}) => {
                    return <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                }}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument passed to renderItem is an object of the form

```
{ item, index, separators }
```

The braces allow you to destructure the argument and directly access the `item` field.

The signature is defined by the implementation of the FlatList component. If you want to see what that looks like, you can find it in the React Native repository.